# ScrollView sin usar UIscrolView

Tags: ios, swift

Buenas quiero implementar un scrollView pero sin utilizar el `UIScrollView`.
No puedo utilizar el `UIScrollView` por que `CVCalendar` tiene un problema el Framework y cuando se añade un `ScrollView` deja de funcionar.

Por eso estoy buscando alguna alternativa de agregar el Scroll mediate código, si alguien sabe como hacerlo o que me proporcione un enlace de ayuda.

Comment: ¿Has creado el issue en Github para alertar al desarrollador y que lo arregle? Es probable que sea la mejor forma. Por otro lado, explica qué quieres hacer y cómo se ha de comportar y así podremos darte alternativas...

Comment: si lo comente pero loo van a arreglar en la V2.0 que se encuentra en desarrollo. Lo que quiero hacer es un calendario con eventos que los eventos aparecen en unas imágenes y esas imágenes llegan al borde de la pantalla abajo y necesito poner un scroll para que deslize para arriba

Comment: Y si colocas un tableview o un collection view? De esta manera no estas añadiendo un scroll directamente

Comment: Yo en esas situaciones utilizo un `UITableView` con una sola celda, y ahí agrego todos los elementos. La tabla ya tiene un scroll y te evitas lidiar con `UIScrollView`, y se adapta vertical u horizontal.

Comment: Puedes usar stack views !!! es la forma mas fácil de hacerlo sin agregar código

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, te dejo el siguiente código y un enlace al [proyecto](https://github.com/frndev/Simulate-Scroll) que he hecho para solucionar tu duda, puede que no sea la mejor solución, pero espero que te sirva de alguna manera. Básicamente es una UIView con un UIPanGestureRecognizer

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addPanGesture()
    }

    func addPanGesture() {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didScroll))
        self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }

    func didScroll(sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .recognized {

            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.scrollView).y
            let y = self.scrollView.frame.origin.y
            let scrollViewSize = self.scrollView.frame.size.height
            let viewSize = self.view.frame.size.height
            var newY = y + translation

            // These conditions avoids scrollView to leave the screen

            if newY > 0 {
                newY = 0
            } else if newY + scrollViewSize <  viewSize {
                newY = -scrollViewSize + viewSize
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

                self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                               y: newY,
                                               width: self.scrollView.frame.width,
                                               height: scrollViewSize)
            })
        }

    }
}
```